# Android NDK debugging and question marks in backtrace

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, backtrace

before I say anything more, let me just start with stating that the software is perfectly sane, it's taken from Android Samples and it does not crash :).

My team has been struggling to get some sane backtraces from android lately. We do get output from LibC and... it seems that this is the only component we get valid backtraces from. Anything else generates just question marks and shallow backtraces (so it usually breaks at first *??*, nothing more is shown beyond that point, so we usually see - for example - only *vsnprintf* and... that's pretty much it.

We've been experimenting, and eventually created a whole new project copied almost entirely from samples: native-activity, with few modifications:

- AndroidManifest.xml has right flags set:

  ```
  <application android:label="@string/app_name" 
      android:hasCode="false" android:debuggable="true" >
  ```
- build.xml has a prebuild rule:

  ```
   <target name="-pre-build">
       <exec executable="${env.ANDROID_NDK}/ndk-build" failonerror="true">
           <arg value="NDK_DEBUG=1" />
       </exec>
   </target>
  ```
- *Application.mk* has a definition:

  ```
  APP_OPTIM := debug
  ```
- even *Android.mk* file has been tweaked some:

  ```
  LOCAL_MODULE    := test
  LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.c
  LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog -landroid -lEGL -lGLESv1_CM
  LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := android_native_app_glue
  LOCAL_CFLAGS := -g3 -ggdb -O0
  LOCAL_CPPFLAGS := -g3 -ggdb -O0
  include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
  ```

we experimented with `-gstabs+` and `-g -ggdb`, but it still gives us the same backtrace:

```
(gdb) bt
#1  0x4005b384 in epoll_wait () from libc.so
#2  0x40120eaa in ?? ()
```

the second call is - no doubt - native code, most likely `ALooper_pollAll`, which calls libc's `epoll_wait`. but there is no reference reaching to `android_main`.

The code is perfectly good. I can hit *c* and let it run for hours without any crashes, but stopping it and printing backtrace - no matter when - always returns the same two lines.

We would deeply appreciate all help and suggestions; we ran into some trouble with our product and.. well the only means we can think of right now are truly medieval.

Answer (score 0):

well after some more investigations we figured things out.
in some cases our backtrace had 20 or more levels, in some it was almost entirely gone. the reason is that android libraries, that are used for native programming are usually stripped from debugging symbols and optimized, and therefore system is unable to provide any more details than whatever points to our / your code.

that said, debugging native code on actual devices is often nearly impossible...